# Using Common Lisp CLOS objects as keys in a hashtable?

Tags: key, hashtable, common-lisp, clos

I'd like to use Common Lisp CLOS objects as keys in a hashtable.  I thought it would be as simple as this:

```
(defclass my-class () ((a :accessor a :initarg a)))

(defun my-class= (my-instance-1 my-instance-2)
(equal (a my-instance-1) (a my-instance-2)))

(defparameter my-hash-table (make-hash-table :test #'my-class=))
```

Checking out the Common Lisp Hyperspec, it seems I can only use eq, eql, equal, or equalp to test equality.

Is there any way I can do this?  Or is this just a really stoopid thing to do, and that's why the standard doesn't allow it?

Answer (score 9):

Common Lisp standard does not provide any mechanism to provide additional test functions for hash-tables (beyond standard ones). You have 2 options:

1. Use genhash [genhash](http://www.cliki.net/genhash) which is portable hash-table implementation (not compatible with built-in ones)
2. Use non-standard extensions:
3. SBCL has `sb-ext:define-hash-table-test` function ([documentation](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Hash-Table-Extensions.html))
4. Clisp has a similar function `ext:define-hash-table-test` ([documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/clisp/impnotes/defhash.html))
5. Allegro and Lispworks accept non-standard values for `:test` argument and has `:hash-function` argument ([Allegro](http://www.franz.com/support/documentation/8.1/doc/implementation.htm#cl-make-hash-table-2), [Lispworks](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/LW/html/lw-608.htm)).

Comment: Genhash is, if nothing else, pretty stable (and goverened by a CDR).