# comparing CLOS objects

Tags: common-lisp, clos

I am wondering why there is no built-in equality operator in Common Lisp for comparing CLOS objects (standard-classes). For instance, "equalp" can be applied on arrays, structures, hash-tables, however not on objects.

I assume a new test which descends an object and checks if slot-values are equalp can be written by the programmer, but I wonder if there is a reason for this not being part of the standard, since I imagine it's a fairly common thing to do? For instance, it seems the test functions for "make-hash-table" must be one of the built-in ones*, thus, I don't really see how to use objects as keys or values in a hash table.

*I've noticed there is a related question ([Using Common Lisp CLOS objects as keys in a hashtable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605077/using-common-lisp-clos-objects-as-keys-in-a-hashtable)), however it does not really answer my question.

Thanks and cheers!

M

Comment: See for example: http://www.nhplace.com/kent/PS/EQUAL.html

Comment: Usually if you're comparing two objects, you either want to check if they are the same object, which you can do with `EQ` (works with hashtables as well), or you want to check if a specific slot is equal, which naturally requires you to write your own comparison function.

Comment: With a bit of MOP you can write generic equality test, say `EQUAL?` that does `EQUALP` on everything except classes instances (i.e. `STANDARD-OBJECT`), and does `EQUAL?` on all the slots (of course you must check if objects belong to the same class first and slots a bound). Slow, but probably what you want in 99% of cases,

Comment: Whats wrong with just using `EQ` which **Returns true if its arguments are the same, identical object**?

Comment: @mobiuseng It would be cool if you wrote an answer based on that. Slow or not - sometimes people have to do what they have to do. It could also be a (slighty faster) idea to have a `(defgeneric equal? (x y) (:documentation "compares two instances, usually of the same class for equality."))` , which then could be implemented for just those class instances, the application needs.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot offer a definitive answer, but I suspect that a part of the reason is [historical](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hysterical-reasons.html):
CLOS was added to ANSI CL *after* the spec for [`equalp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_equalp.htm) was finalized.

Note that `equalp` works on [`structure-object`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/08_.htm)s as you expect it.
Note also that structures have a [readable print syntax](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dhm.htm)
while [CLOS objects](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/07_.htm) lack it.

**However**, this might not be such a big oversight as one might think at first.

CLOS objects can be relatively heavy-weight;
given that [slot accessors](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/07_eb.htm)
are [generic functions](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/07_f.htm),
figuring out object equality can quickly devolve to comparing functions.